# Equivalent to select concat in doctrine query builder

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have a doctrine query builder similar to this

```
$builder
  ->select(
    u.name,
    a.address
  )
  ->from(User::class, 'u')
  ->innerJoin(Details::class, 'd')
;
```

there is a relation oneToMany between these two entities, so, if for user1 there are 3 lines in the Details entity, this query will return 3 lines.

is there a way to have one single line, having the 3 addresses as a comma separated list, like when using select concat in standard SLQ?

thanks

Comment: is this TSQL or MySQL?

Comment: this is querybuilder

Comment: yes, it is query builder, but which database driver are you connecting to?

Comment: ah sorry, it is mysql